# pinch zoom, pan mapview android

Tags: android, events, android-mapview

I want to handle pinch zoom, pan on a mapview and fire an asynctask to load some data from a backend server, asynctask already done. i dont know how to handle those events.
thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this code for reference [PinchMapView.java](http://code.google.com/p/android-pinch/source/browse/trunk/src/com/nikkoaiello/mobile/android/PinchMapView.java?r=2)

Comment: isn't it implemented by default pinch zoom on mapview

Comment: Wasn't your question how to detect Zoom/Pinch events? The code linked does just that.

Comment: yes and pann through map, but i dont want to implement it for a mapview, is'nt already implemented already by android? i just want to get kind of notification when that event is fired